# Split Question: Bergelson Multiplicative Density of "Even-like" sets

Tags: combinatorics

This post splits the post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026755/questions-about-bergelson-multiplicative-upper-density?noredirect=1#comment2093891_1026755 into one more concentrated series of questions.  It is largely copied directly.

Let $\mathbb{P} \subset \mathbb{N}$ be the set of all primes.  Let $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, F_n = \{a_n \prod_{i=1}^n (p_i^{r_i}): a_n \in \mathbb{N}, p_i \in \mathbb{P}, r_i \in [0, N_i(n)] \cap \mathbb{Z} \forall i \in \mathbb{N} \cap [1, n] \}$ where $\forall i \in \mathbb{N} \cap [1, n], N_i(n) \to \infty$.  (For concreteness, you can take $N_i(n) = n \forall i$, but please mention when you do and if it actually matters. Likewise, $a_n = 1 \forall n$ is allowed, but just mention it when it comes up.) Denote the Bergelson multiplicative upper density of the set $A$ by $\overline{\operatorname{d}^{\times}}(A) = \limsup_{N \to \infty} \big(\frac{A \cap F_n}{|F_n|} \big)$.  Let $\operatorname{d}$ denote the additive natural density.

Many of the following are my speculations. But, being a novice to this notion of density (I do not yet even have a great grasp of what it intuitively means, although I am working on it), I am having difficulties proving or disproving these claims. I am mostly just feeling things out at the moment.

---

Question 1: $\overline{\operatorname{d}^{\times}}(2 \mathbb{N} - 1) =^? 0$?

Question 2: Let $E = \{\prod_{i=1}^k (p_i^{r_i}) < \infty: p_i \in \mathbb{P} \forall i \in \mathbb{N}, \sum_{i=1}^k (r_i) \in 2 \mathbb{N} \}$.  Then $\overline{\operatorname{d}^{\times}}(E) =^? \frac{1}{2}$?

(Question 2 might have an answer that follows from: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026715/question-about-a-possible-relationship-between-additive-and-bergelson-multiplica.)

Question 3: Let $\tilde{E}_k = \{\prod_{i=1}^k (p_i^{r_i}) < \infty: \forall i \in \mathbb{N}, p_i \in \mathbb{P}, r_i \in 2 \mathbb{N} \}$.  What is  $\overline{\operatorname{d}^{\times}}(\tilde{E}_k)$?

Bonus 1: Prove that $\operatorname{d}(E) = \frac{1}{2}$.

---

1.) I know that the set of odd numbers is, obviously, missing 2 and any number that it divides while it also contains every other prime power.  Thus, there are a lot of elements of $F_n$ that are missing in $2 \mathbb{N} - 1$, but it, at this time, is not readily apparent that *most* of them are in fact missing. Would the same be true if we took instead the set of all prime powers that are not divisible by $3$ (or any specific given prime)? I do not see why not.  But, if that is so, then how [in some way] is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \big( \frac{|2 \mathbb{N} \cap F_n|}{|F_n|} \big) =^? 1$ special (presuming that it is even correct; see Question 4 in the initially linked post)?  Are multiples of powers of 2 are almost all of the numbers in this sense?  That does not seem very obvious to me. But I do guess that half of all natural numbers are even, while less are divisible by other given primes- I still do not see why $2 \mathbb{N}$ would be basically everything though. [I originally asked Question 4 along with Question 1 in our to pointedly demonstrate my hiccup in understanding in this area.  I do not know whether or not the resolution to Question 4 is affirmative, but if it is, I understand less than I would like. An explanation here, in particular, would be much appreciated.]

Comment: Even a hint or explanation would be helpful.